# iOS app rejected because app crash on iOS 10.2 on ipv6

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, ipv6

I have uploaded my app to Apple store. I am using iOS 10.2. After upload, I got a rejection message:

> Your app crashes on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.2 connected to an IPv6 network when we:
>
> Specifically, we found that the app crashes after sending messages on Wi-Fi

How can I solve this?

Comment: hey , plz check the webservices u r hitting in app, Also check the server side OS installed , does it support iPV6?

Comment: Are you using some kind of Reachability class? Some of those don't handle IPv6 correctly.

Comment: Hello. I also got the same kind of issue. App rejected with this message from Apple:
"Your app crashed on iPad running iOS 10.2.1 connected to an IPv6 network". The problem is I am not using IPV6 and have no way to do a real test.
Did you find a solution working for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you app contains webservices and you have implemented NSURConnection then please convert all NSURLConnection to NSURLSession  . .

Answer (score 1):

My App got rejected for the same reason, but it was not the issue. The reason my app got rejected because it got crashed on login button click.

It was working when i compile and run with xcode (ie xcode 8.2.1) but apple said it was crashing.

So i tried running it in **release** mode because we usually run our app in **debug** mode when we run on xcode.

from

[image]

to

[image]

And my App crashed when i ran it on release mode and i found the bug, it happened when the compiler tried to optimise a decryption function.
I think there is some issue with the new llvm 8.0 compiler.

Now my App got even approved by AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is fairly simple, you're going to have to try and reproduce the crash and fix it.

Apple won't let apps into the App Store of which it finds crashes for. I'd recommend finding a friend/family member who has an IPv6 enabled network (if you can't enable it yourself) and attempting to use your app in various conditions under that network.

Comment: its my issue brother please answer me briefly what i do to solve it.

Comment: From Apple
2. 1 PERFORMANCE: APP COMPLETENESS
Performance - 2.1


Your app crashed on an iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.2 connected to an IPv6 network when we:

1) Launch the app.
2) Enter in the provided demo account credentials.
3) Tap on the Login button.
4) App crashes. 

This occurred when your app was used:

- On Wi-Fi

We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Next Steps

Please revise your app and test it on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to ensure that it runs as expected.

Comment: Sorry brother, you need to fix your crash, I don't have your code so I don't know your exact problem

Answer (score 0):

The App Review network, like the networks deployed by service providers, does support IPv6-to-IPv6 connectivity. Thus, if your server supports IPv6, your app will talk to it directly, without going through the NAT64 translator.

Please check your link is support ipv6 or not use this [LINK](http://ready.chair6.net/)

and [read more](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1)

Comment: when i click on LINK then search https://www.google.com.pk it returns.http://ready.chair6.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.pk

Comment: @vky please if you are using AFNetworking...you updated AFNetworking to last version and Apple's Reachability class too, you can try this, I hope it'll work.

Comment: @vky Transitioning to IPv6-only networks https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4971

Comment: i am using NSURLConnection in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a CDN (Example: Cloudflare) to your domain, change nameservers accordingly and make sure IPv6 compatibility feature is turned ON. This worked for me